# Cannot find file precomp.hpp when installing opencv 4.0 on VS17

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm trying to install openCV with TBB, IPP and opencv_contrib and I'm getting an error when trying to build on the VS17, hope you guys can help me.

```
Error:

Code    Description                                                 
C1083   Cannot open include file 'precomp.hpp': No such file or directory

Project            File            Line
Opencv_tracking    feature.cpp     42
```

CMake config:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17134.0 to target Windows 10.0.16299.
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.7")
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.6")
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "3.4")
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "3.2")
AVX_512F is not supported by C++ compiler
AVX512_SKX is not supported by C++ compiler
Dispatch optimization AVX512_SKX is not available, skipped
libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 1.5.3, BUILD = opencv-4.0.0-alpha-libjpeg-turbo
Found TBB (env): C:/OpenCV_LIBRARY/source/tbb2019_20180718oss/lib/intel64/vc14/tbb.lib
found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]
at: C:/OpenCV_LIBRARY/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win
found Intel IPP IW sources: 2017.0.3
at: C:/OpenCV_LIBRARY/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_win
Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES) 
LAPACK requires BLAS
A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
Caffe:   NO
Protobuf:   NO
Glog:   NO
freetype2:   NO
harfbuzz:    NO
Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
Module opencv_optflow disabled because opencv_ximgproc dependency can't be resolved!
Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp
Tesseract:   NO

General configuration for OpenCV 4.0.0-alpha =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            C:/OpenCV_LIBRARY/source/opencv_contrib-master/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2018-10-18T17:46:38Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.16299 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.12.2
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1914

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (8 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.14.26433.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi      /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP4   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG  /Zi
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi      /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP4   /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi        /MP4    /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG  /Zi
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi        /MP4  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO  /debug
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann fuzzy hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator line_descriptor ml objdetect phase_unwrapping photo plot python_bindings_generator reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab
    Disabled:                    js world
    Disabled by dependency:      optflow
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv freetype hdf java matlab ovis python2 python3 sfm viz
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.34)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.9)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    Video for Windows:           YES
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 58.18.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 58.12.100)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 56.14.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 5.1.100)
      avresample:                YES (ver 4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES

  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2019.0 interface 11000)

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]
           at:                   C:/OpenCV_LIBRARY/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2017.0.3)
              at:                C:/OpenCV_LIBRARY/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_win
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                C:/OpenCV_LIBRARY/source/opencv-master/opencv-master/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python (for build):            NO

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/OpenCV_LIBRARY/build/install
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
```

Visual Studio Error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju8rg.png)

Comment: please edit your post make it more readable .thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest to stick with the stable release of OpenCV, such as 3.4.3 -- 4.0 is in beta, and you're still trying to use alpha based on the CMake output. Generally, if you can't resolve obscure issues, and don't intend to work on the OpenCV source code itself to implement new features or fix bugs, then it's better to stay away from the bleeding edge.